# Adjusting the width of Select List in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery Mobile. I am unable to change the width of my select list. I tried something like this but its not working :

```
<label> Give a rating:</label>
<select width="100px" style="width: 100px" id="rating_restaurant">
    <option value="1star">1-star</option>
    <option value="2star">2-star</option>
    <option value="3star">3-star</option>
    <option value="4star">4-star</option>
    <option value="5star">5-star</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery? Where's your jQuery code?

Comment: jQuery mobile recreates the select and uses 100% of the width of the container, so use a wrapping element, and set the width on that.